# Filter list of rules based on a capability

Tags: capabilities, user-roles

I'm trying to get a list of roles and filter them by a specific capability (custom). I've ran across [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/getting-a-list-of-currently-available-roles-on-a-wordpress-site), but I'd like to filter the roles by whether they're capable to, say, `edit_post`.

-Zack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, but should be easily extendable(or something you can take ideas from).

```
function roles_have_cap( $roles = false, $cap ) {
    global $wp_roles;

    if( !isset( $wp_roles ) || !isset( $cap ) )
        return false;

    if( !$roles )
        $roles = array_keys( $wp_roles->roles );

    if( !is_array( $roles ) )
        $roles = array( $roles );

    $hascap = array();
    foreach( $roles as $role ) {
        if( !isset( $wp_roles->roles[$role]['capabilities'][$cap] ) || ( 1 != $wp_roles->roles[$role]['capabilities'][$cap] ) )
            continue;

        $hascap[] = $role;
    }

    if( empty( $hascap ) )
        return false;

    return $hascap;
}
```

- First argument takes either a singular role name(string) or an array of roles to check have a particular cap.
- Second argument takes a singular capability to check for(string).

**Example usage:**

```
$role_can_edit_pages = roles_have_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_pages' ); 
// Result
// array( 0 => administrator )
```

If the function returned false you'd know the role(s) does not have the cap, ie..

```
if( !$role_can_edit_pages )
// Role cannot not edit pages
```

Else, the result is an array of roles that do have the cap(whether you passed in a single role or several).

You could trim it down and just have a return value if that's preferred, but you mentioned wanting a list of roles that have a cap, so i naturally assumed an array would be a logical choice..

Converting an array to a string is fairly easy, and you can even use your own seperator, simply call `implode()`, like so...(using the example variable from earlier)..

```
echo implode( ' | ', $role_can_edit_pages ); // | (pipe is the example seperator here)
```

You could also move the implode into the function to avoid having to do implodes when calling the function, and do note, implode will work correctly on a single item array to(ie. you'll get a string with no seperator).

I hope that's helpful in anycase... :)

**EDIT:**
Function will now look at all the roles if the first arg($roles) is set to false.

Comment: Looks alright, I can follow the basic logic. Though, logistical problem I foresee. Your function checks **only** the specified roles for the requested capability (No problem to me, I can rewrite it easily from your logic). In fact, I can see two functions branching out from this function you provided here. ;)

Comment: Added the option in for you, set first arg to false to look at all roles... :)